# update blank records based on join with another table

Tags: mysql

I have a table in which certain records contains one column value as ZERO. now I want to write a job which will take records from another table based on key and update in first table.

**its kind of update table A based on join with table B where A certain records are blank.**

I tried following syntax with temporary table to first get all records which contains zero for that column and then using join to three tables , one in which need to update , one is temporary table and last one from where i will get the original value.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `blank_raw_ids`;

CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE blank_raw_ids (SELECT * FROM ct  where ct.rawid=0);



    UPDATE ct  
      INNER JOIN main_raw_ids as m  ON ct.bid=m.bid
      INNER JOIN blank_raw_ids  as r ON r.bid =m.bid
    SET ct.rawid=r.rawid;
```

I also feel that I am not able to properly use the temp table as i am still joining with main table and blank table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

But the `blank_raw_ids` only has rows where rawid=0, so if you set `ct.rawid=r.rawid` you will always `set 0 = 0` which has no net effect.

I think I understand you want to copy the values of `main_raw_ids.rawid` to replace `ct.rawid` where `ct.rawid` is 0.

Wouldn't the following do that?

```
UPDATE ct
  INNER JOIN main_raw_ids AS m ON ct.bid=m.bid
SET ct.rawid = m.rawid
WHERE ct.rawid = 0;
```

No need for a temporary table.

Comment: my only question for this answer here , whether where clause will run first and joins the rows where its zero or join first and then filter records ?

Comment: Depends on indexes. You haven't included the `show create table` output for your tables, so I can't answer that. You should use `EXPLAIN` to see how MySQL will use the indexes for this update statement.